# UIImageview/UIVIew in UIWindow cannot rotate to landscape

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, rotation, uiwindow

In my AppDelegate, I have an uiwindow like this. Inside that, there are uiimageview as background.

[image]

Problems is that those Imageview aren't rotated when iPad is rotated and status bar is also in landscape position already. May I know how to do?

Edited: If I listen to orientation change, my image view is rotated but I want to set that image view to the origin (0,0) of device. However, it look like uiwindow is offset in horizontal position. Now, I am setting origin of image view as origin of uiwindow. Then, my image view is also offset. How shall I do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the correct behavior. UIWindow objects doesn't support rotations.
To do that, you should rotate them by yourself listening to `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` notification.
Managing rotation in a window is a little bit tricky, also because during rotation animation you should be able to detect the rotation direction to make a good user experience.
In my opinion is better if you embed you image views in a view of a view controllers.

Comment: Thanks. I will later make self.window.rootviewcontroller = loginVC , etc. However, in my uiwindow, I want to have uiimageview as background. I am trying to set frame of image view and it is wrong (as described in my edited question). How shall I do?

Comment: I told you that is tricky, because even when you rotate the coordinate system of the window is always in the same physical angle

Comment: yes. Because image view right side seem like it can cover uiwindow and I thought it is possible. Only origin is offset. I will try your method.

Comment: This one of the really few custom libraries that creates alert views over a UIWindow, you can see its source code to check for inspiration in rotation mechanism https://github.com/hfossli/AGWindowView

Comment: wow..so easy and powerful..Thanks thanks. I am using that now.